# how to fetch data from json in angular 4

Tags: json, angular, api

Hi everyone plz help me I have Json string which is I am getting from Node api .I want only single value from that string.

I have service.ts from which I am calling api and subscribe the data on my component file .

Json string is [{"_id":5,"name":"ram,shyam,kamal,kishore"}]

I want only  name value. how to achieve this.

service.ts code is given below

```
empservicecall() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Employee")

  }
```

component.ts code is given below

```
GetEmpName(){
   this.Emp.empservicecall()
   .subscribe(
     response =>{
       this.name=response.json})

 }
```

it is not working and also error is coming in this code at line response.json().
plz help me

Comment: What's the exact version of Angular that you're using?

Comment: Did you try `response[0].name`?

Comment: @SiddAjmer I am using angular 4

Comment: 4. what? 4.0 or 4.3?

Comment: Does _http://localhost:3000/api/Employee_ only return the employee's name?

Comment: response[0].name is not working

Comment: Check out the `map`-operator of _RxJS_

Comment: @sclonzo return json string [{"_id":5,"name":"ram,shyam,kamal,kishore"}]

Comment: @sclonzo how to use map operator

Comment: @user1220461, check out my answer.

Comment: @JuanDM JSON.parse(response.json)[0].name is not working

Comment: @user1220461 Try this JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))[0].name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue completely depends on which version of Angular you are on and whether you're using `Http` or `HttpClient`.

**If you're using `HttpClient`, then:**

```
empservicecall() {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Employee");
}
```

And in your Component:

```
GetEmpName(){
  this.Emp.empservicecall()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.name = response[0].name
    });
}
```

**If you're using `Http`(which has been deprecated after the introduction of `HttpClient` in Angular 4.3 BTW), then:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

empservicecall() {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Employee")
    .map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

And in your Component:

```
GetEmpName(){
  this.Emp.empservicecall()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.name = response[0].name
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment .Error is not coming but still I am not getting the value of name.it is showing blank value

Comment: @user1220461, try logging the `response` inside the `subscribe` to the console and tell me what you're seeing on the screen? According to the OP, it was an array with just one object in it. This one object had a key named `name` in it. Hence we assigned it to the class property `name` by writing `this.name = response[0].name`

Comment: .it is showing error response.json is not a function

Comment: What is the type of `http` in your code? Is it `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: now I am using HttpClient . error is gone and the result in console is coming like this 0: {_id: 5, name:"ram,shyam,kamal,kishore"}

Comment: thanks for valuable comment plz help  how to Get only  name node  value

Comment: Then it's definitely an array of Objects with just one object in it. Read my first comment on this answer where I've tried to explain what I'm doing.

Comment: `response[0]` would give you the whole object on the 0th index of the array. `response[0].name` will give you the `name` node on the object on the 0th index of the array

Comment: I am using the same code as  you have written in this article but still I am not getting value of name...you are right but I do not know where is my silly mistake

Comment: thank u very much  finally I got the result.You are right